# Small issue stying the mobile menu

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a good job in styling the mobile menu for the client website but have some coding issue that trying to bring logo section and hamburger button behind the mobile menu.

So when the user clicks on hamburger button they not going to see the  logo section and hamburger button.

So I already did a z-index but don't work. Here a link to a site so re-size your screen to see the menu and don't have any javascript & jquery add to site at the moment.

Site Preview:
https://brandonpowell.github.io/alegacyleftbehind/

```
@media (max-width: 480px){
  nav{
    height:100%;
    width:100%
    }
    nav .bottom-navbar{
      background-color:#212121
    }
    nav .bottom-navbar .logo{
      position:absolute
    }
    nav .bottom-navbar .bt-close{
      position:absolute;
      background-color:#51237f;
      padding:9px;
      display:block;
      top:0;
      width:100%
      }
      nav .bottom-navbar .bt-close .close-image{
        width:50px;
        padding:10px;
        float:right;
      }
        nav .bottom-navbar .bt-close .main-title{
          color:white;
          padding:20px 10px;
          text-transform:uppercase;
          font-size:13pt;font-family:Montserrat,sans-serif;
          letter-spacing:1px
          }
          nav .bottom-navbar .nav-menu{
            display:block;width:34px;margin:36px;float:right
          }
          nav ul li{
            float:none;
            display:block;
            letter-spacing:1px;
            padding:1.9em 15px;
            border-bottom:2px solid #2e2e2e;width:100%
            }
            nav ul li a{
              color:white;
              font-size:1.6em
              }
              li:hover{
                background-color:#2e2e2e;
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#ffffff
              }
              ul{
                padding-left:0px;
                margin:0;
              }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered changing their opacity to 0 and setting their pointer events to none instead of attempting to hide them behind the menu?

Visually it will have the same effect, and can be triggered with jQuery by adding a class to both. The CSS code for that class could be:

```
.hidestuff{
opacity:0;
pointer-events:none;
}
```

Once you remove this class they will go back to being visible and clickable. This has the added benefit of allowing for them to fade in and out using CSS transitions.

Andy

Comment: No, I have not thought of doing that could explain little better to me, please him still learn Jquery or could link a tutorial.

Comment: w3 Schools has a good tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp